# how to use remember me in custom membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web-config, membership-provider

I use custom membership provider in web apllication 4. and use this code in web.config:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

membership and login is working but remember me is not working.

**Edit:**

and use this code for login user:

```
public static void SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
    {
        using (EntitiesConnection EF = new EntitiesConnection())
        {
            var obj = (from m in EF.Memberships.ToList()
                       where m.Username == userName
                       select m).FirstOrDefault();

            var userId = obj.UserId;
            var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                                userName, // user name
                                DateTime.Now,             //creation
                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
                                persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                                userData);

            var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

            if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
            {
                cookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `cookieless="UseCookies"`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

[**Updated**]

you should create persistent cookie when user logging, for example

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and in your login action:

```
if(ValidateUser(loginModel))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
}
```

Comment: "remember me" not related with CustomMembershipProvider. Only you should use persistent cookie. I updated my answer, use like that

Comment: I update my question. i use this code for login user in website but remember me is not working

Answer (score 0):

> It seems you are using Forms Authentication. If so refer this..
>   [Remember me checkbox does not work with Forms Authentication](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

This below line will set that

```
 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("UserName",true);
```

if the second parm is true ,remember me is activated ,otherwise remember me is not activated

and Create a machinekey using this [online tool](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) and add it to your web.config.

Comment: did you create machinekey in your web.confiq file ? ?

Comment: Yes. i use machinekey in web.config